# Movie storage on Xbox

Tags: xbox-360

I have a 4GB Xbox and want to download an HD Movie. As HD Movies are about 10GB, can I download the movie to a USB stick? I can't seem to find where to direct the download to the stick as opposed to the internal hard drive.

Comment: Awesome info.  Thanks very much.   Looks like I'll go figure out how to the do the 320GB replacement.   FYI...maybe I did something wrong but "The Butler" in HD wouldn't download b/c it said it was 9.7GB so I did exagerate a bit or two.   I have DSL and nothing available to upgrade to currently but hopefully that changes soon.   Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not believe you may download movies to the USB drive, Similarly you cannot transfer music to the drive from the console and vice versa.

You may transfer the content once downloaded but otherwise the best bet would be to plug in your flashdrive and transfer the content (Y button in the memory screen) to the drive then begin the download. You may also stream the content from the Xbox Movie Store, if I'm not mistaken. HD Movies should NOT be 10GB even at 1080p. Thats equivalent to a blu-ray Disc rip. You should be able to download it and watch it on the empty 4GB.

[**YOU CAN ALWAYS STREAM YOUR CONTENT**](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/xbox-video/buying-and-renting-videos#b1efce9f2d194c67819836ee456238f8)

[This Screenshot](http://www.trmk.org/images/mk9/season_pass_step_5_follow_prompts.jpg) of the Xbox Download Screen should provide you with the reason as to why you cannot choose a different storage option.

There is always getting a 320GB Hard drive for your Xbox 360 S as well which would fix your problem entirely.

I will look into it but this has been my past experience.